# Magento paypal express billing agreement is not working

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am trying to setup billing agreement with paypal express checkout method in my magento test server.

I did all settings as per below magento wiki blog.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-express-checkout-for-magento-community

and I also enabled reference transaction settings in my paypal manager account as per below link.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/updating_transaction_setting.htm

all settings are looks like OK, but after placing an order with paypal express checkout and selecting billing agreement option yes for customer, I am able to place order successfully but it is not creating any billing agreement in my account and even I am not able to see any billing agreement in admin customer account section.

If I am trying to create new billing agreement from my account its giving below error.

"PayPal gateway has rejected request. Merchant not enabled for reference transactions (#11452: Merchant not enabled for reference transactions)."

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: I contact paypal technical support and they enabled reference transaction settings for my sandbox account and it is working now. :)

Comment: Then add it as an answer and mark the question as solved